# QTableView + QAbstractTableModel: Move rows via drag'n'drop

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have a simple `QAbstractTableModel`-based model and a `QTableView` for it.

My aim is simple as well: allow to move/reorder rows via drag'n'drop. Notes:

- D'n'd changes inside `QTableView` should be reflected in my model;
- D'n'd supposed to be internal - movement should be performed only inside my view, no external MIME exports;
- I want to drag and drop *whole* row. Separate items should *not* be dragged or dropped;
- Dragging horizontal header is not a suitable solution for me because I want headers to be hided and because I want to let user to grab row at *any* place to drag it;

I'm reeeally close to my aim. But still it doesn't work as I expect. Now I can drag rows, but seems that *any* cell can accept a drop, although I've specified `Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled` only for a global table's parent and do not specify this flag for actual table items because I do not want to drop to them, I want somehow to drop "between the rows", just to perform row movement. Because table items for some reason can accept drops I get curious behaviour: if a drop to *first* cell of any row, I achieve exactly what I want: my row moves correctly. But if I drop to *nonfirst* cell of any row, it goes totally wrong. But it's better to show a pic of what happens here:

[image]

My code (minimal sample that has exactly my problem):

**main.cpp**

```
void setupView(QTableView &t)
{
    t.verticalHeader()->hide();
    t.horizontalHeader()->hide();
    t.horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

    t.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    t.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);

    t.setDragEnabled(true);
    t.setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    t.setAcceptDrops(true);
    t.viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
    t.setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
    t.setDragDropMode(QTableView::InternalMove);
    t.setDragDropOverwriteMode(false);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;

    QTableView *table = new QTableView(&w);
    setupView(*table);
    table->setModel(new TableModel);

    w.setCentralWidget(table);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**tablemodel.cpp**

```
#include "tablemodel.h"

TableModel::TableModel()
{
    // m_data is a QList<QStringList>
    m_data = {
        {"Name", "Kelly"},
        {"Age", "19"},
        {"Gender", "Female"},
    };
}

int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return m_data.size();
}

int TableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return 2;
}

QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &i, int r) const
{
    return (r == Qt::DisplayRole) ? m_data[i.row()][i.column()] : QVariant();
}

QVariant TableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int r) const
{
    return QVariant();
}

Qt::ItemFlags TableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags f = Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable
                    | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled;

    if(!index.isValid()) {
        f |= Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;
    }

    return f;
}

Qt::DropActions TableModel::supportedDropActions() const
{
    return Qt::MoveAction | Qt::CopyAction;
}

bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &i, const QVariant &v, int r)
{
    if(r == Qt::EditRole || r == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        m_data[i.row()][i.column()] = v.toString();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool TableModel::setItemData(const QModelIndex &i, const QMap<int, QVariant> &roles)
{
    if(!roles.contains(Qt::EditRole) && !roles.contains(Qt::DisplayRole)) {
        return false;
    }

    m_data[i.row()][i.column()] = roles[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();
    return true;
}

bool TableModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
        m_data.insert(row, QStringList({"", ""}));
    }
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}

bool TableModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
        m_data.removeAt(row);
    }
    endRemoveRows();
    return true;
}

bool TableModel::moveRows(const QModelIndex &srcParent, int srcRow, int count,
                          const QModelIndex &dstParent, int dstChild)
{
    beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), srcRow, srcRow + count - 1, QModelIndex(), dstChild);
    for(int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
        m_data.insert(dstChild + i, m_data[srcRow]);
        int removeIndex = dstChild > srcRow ? srcRow : srcRow+1;
        m_data.removeAt(removeIndex);
    }
    endMoveRows();
    return true;
}
```

Please, give me some hint, what is wrong with model or view setup now.

**UPD**

For those who is interested in the solution:

```cpp
bool TableModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    Q_UNUSED(column);

    if(row == -1) {
        row = rowCount();
    }

    return QAbstractTableModel::dropMimeData(data, action, row, 0, parent);
}
```

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, that's exactly the solution! It solved my problem. Copy your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @NikolaiShalakin, I have the same problem, and wanted to ask if it could be possible to post the entire solution with the implementation of `dropMimeData` please

Comment: @Emanuele sure, please check out, I've added it to the bottom of question

Comment: Your solution is great, but it doesn't belong in the question. Please edit the question, remove the solution from there, and post it as your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `dropMimeData` method to your model and implement it properly. If the drop on the first column works fine for you, you could probably simply call `QAbstractItemModel::dropMimeData` from inside your model's `dropMimeData` with `column` parameter equal to 0 regardless of which column the drop was actually made on.

Answer (score 1):

Nitpick: These two lines are not necessary:

```
t.setAcceptDrops(true);
t.viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
```